# How to get data of a python code in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api

The following is a python code which prints live data from an API of a data feed vendor. I want the data in the panda's data frame but it prints only the following result
"Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []"

```
from truedata_ws.websocket.TD import TD
import time
import pandas as pd
username = ''
password = ''
realtime_port = 8084
url = 'push.truedata.in'
symbols = []
td_obj = TD(username, password, live_port=realtime_port, url=url, log_level=logging.DEBUG, log_format="%(message)s")

print('\nStarting Real Time Feed.... ')

req_ids = td_obj.start_live_data(symbols)
live_data_objs = {}

time.sleep(1)  

for req_id in req_ids:
    print(f'touchlinedata -> {td_obj.touchline_data[req_id]}')
    df=pd.DataFrame(live_data_objs)
    print(df)

@td_obj.trade_callback
def strategy_callback(symbol_id, tick_data):
    print(f'Trade  update > {tick_data}')

while True:
    time.sleep(120)
```

Comment: As far as I can see, `live_data_objs` is an empty dictionary and is never altered.

Comment: can u tell which dictionary to be used to get the data in panda's data frame

Comment: I am not really familiar with `truedata_ws`, but somehow you need to update your dictionary with keys and values before passing it to `pd.DataFrame`. Can you tell me where you are supposed to get the data?

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you pass an empty dictionary as an argument for creating a Data-frame, the Data-Frame you will get back for passing an empty dictionary will be Empty